# Progressively load/unload models in Unity

Tags: c#, blender

I am making a game where you can travel the entirety of a planet. It will be hosted on a server so procedural generation would probably be a bit too much for the server to generate a world for multiple players. I can build the planet and I would like to be able to load it from game files by each client. The server wouldn't need to load or generate any part of the planet in this case.

A planet would have far too many vertices for unity though, so if i were to build it in blender as a multitude of smaller objects could these be loaded/unloaded as the player moves along the planet?

and I understand this might be a little too far out but, can the models be changed in game and saved? say if I placed a building somewhere on the planet, then send this detail over to current and new players.

Thaaanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can stream parts of the world. You can do that in unity too. And you could make live updates. However, the way you're asking the question makes it seem to me as if you're new to this, and working alone - in which case, it'd probably be better to build something that works first. All of the things you've lined up are possible, but not necessarily easy to implement.

Comment: yeah that's it, working alone, but I have built a functioning game. No real point to it yet but the planet is sorta the next thing on the list. I would rather not waste time working on something easier that's not related to my current project. Any links or ideas? thanks

Comment: Like I said, there's no clear one size-fits-it-all solution for this. If you had a relatively static world you could simply divide your area into sectors, in which entering a sector would cause adjacent sectors to be loaded (and far away sectors to be unloaded). You'll probably need a custom solution for this, which is going to take a while - especially if you want some sort of multiplayer component on top of that, which you do the way I understood it. This is going to be difficult and time consuming, I'm afraid.

Comment: Is there a way to access the individual meshes of an object? And then just add the mesh renderer and collider to a prefab?